# Shinobi Pie Chart in iOS - get Label for selected datapoint

Tags: ios, shinobi

In my Shinobi Pie Chart, I want to change the display of the label when a slice is selected.

I believe that this is the method that gets called when a slice is selected, but I don't see how to manipulate the label that is associated with that data point from within this method:

```
- (void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart 
                   toggledSelectionForRadialPoint:(SChartRadialDataPoint *)dataPoint 
                   inSeries:(SChartRadialSeries *)series 
                   atPixelCoordinate:(CGPoint)pixelPoint {
    // What would I put here to get a reference to the label for the given dataPoint?
}
```

None of the objects I have access to in the method seem to have a way to get the labels, but there must be a way.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your code we can't help you with it

Comment: I guess this is more of a question about the ShinobiChart API so I'm not sure what else I could tell you about my code. If that's a bad kind of question to ask here, then I can delete the question. In the Shinobi Chart API, is there a way to get access to the UILabel for a given dataPoint? I'll update the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the method `sChart:alterLabel:forDatapoint:atSliceIndex:inRadialSeries:` in your delegate. This is called as each slice label is laid out. It's also called after a selection event, meaning it should be suitable for altering the labels on selection. However, you won't know if the slice was selected or not - just that it is being redrawn.

If you do need to know whether it is being selected or not, you could always keep track of which data points have been selected via your sChart:toggledSelectionForRadialPoint:.. method.